# Add node js project as a dependency in a java project

Tags: java, node.js, maven

I need to be able to add an existing Node js project as a maven dependency in a java project to be able to call functions from the node js project. I researched quiet a bit but am unable to find a way to do this.
I do not want to embed js in java, rather just import the libraries. Can anybody suggest a way ?

Comment: How do you plan to call a function in JavaScript from Java source code ?

Comment: I plan to use the Java Scripting api as of now but then I'll have to evaluate the js files which I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Kotlin mutlti-platform project which takes a dependency on your node-js package. Then you could create a wrapper kotlin function which calls your node-js function. You can then use this Kotlin package as a dependency in your Java package. Here is more information regarding Kotlin multi-platform: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html